# Using component as a button React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, svg

I have buttons in my React application and I wanted to add the image to them using `SVG`, and as I found out I needed a separate component for my SVG files so I followed this [link](https://blog.lftechnology.com/using-svg-icons-components-in-react-44fbe8e5f91) and made myself a `<SVGIcon />` component.

I tried adding it to a `button` but it does not seem to work. I tried using it as a button, by adding `onClick` to the `<SVGIcon />`, but then the button dissapeared.

How can I use my SVG component but keep the button properties?

```
<SVGIcon  name="list " width={100}/>
<Button onClick={() => this.playPreviousVideo()} disabled={this.state.activeKey === 1} className="mr-3">
    previous()
</Button>
```

Comment: Is your `Button` component from a library? If it's your own component, couldn't you just render it next to `previous()`?

Comment: At the moment I'm using the `rsuite` button

Comment: Alright. Have you tried to write `previous() <SVGIcon name="list" width={100}/>` inside the button?

Comment: Ok that kinda works, the button becomes 10 times bigger than it should or when only using the `<SVGIcon name="list" width={100}/>`, but I think I can think of something from there. Thank you.

Comment: Great! You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution that you might get away with is to just render the `SVGIcon` component as a child to `Button`.

```
<Button
  onClick={() => this.playPreviousVideo()}
  disabled={this.state.activeKey === 1}
  className="mr-3"
>
  previous() <SVGIcon name="list" width={100} />
</Button>
```